# Prevent VSCode opening as root from WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When opening VSCode in a folder using `code .` using my current user, I notice that then it was started as root. The steps that I'm making are to validate this behaviour are:

1. `$ whoami`
   `>> franciscoserrano`
2. `$ mkdir test-dir && ll`
   `>> drwxr-xr-x  2 franciscoserrano franciscoserrano 4.0K Jan 18 19:04 test-dir`
3. `$ cd test-dir`
4. `$ code .`
5. (right after this, inside VSCode's terminal) `$ pwd && whoami`

```
/home/franciscoserrano/projects/test-dir
root
```

Another weird thing is that the VSCode terminal seems to load the .zshrc of my user, this is still inside VSCode terminal:

1. `$ pwd`
   `>> /home/franciscoserrano/projects/test-dir`
2. `$ whoami && cd`
   `>> root`
3. `$ pwd`
   `>> /home/franciscoserrano`

Is this intended? Why making `$ cd` changes to a directory that is not from the user that outputs `$ whoami`? How do I force VSCode to open as the same user as in WSL?

Another detail: when creating files inside the same folder, using the VSCode GUI, those are also created as root:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 18 19:18 hello.c`

Comment: What is your command line executable for the wsl instance?

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command on the windows side fixes this issue for me:

`ubuntu2204.exe config --default-user <wsl-user>`